# install mysql 5.7 to linux 6 - yum tries to install 5.7 el7?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, yum

I'm following the instructions [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-yum-repo-quick-guide/en/) to install MySQL-Community-Server onto a linux 6 aws instance.

Basic commands:
`wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el6-8.noarch.rpm`
`sudo yum localinstall mysql57-community-release-el6-8.noarch.rpm`

then when I search for `mysql57` within my 'new' yum repo with `yum list all |grep mysql57` i get the following:

```
mysql57-community-release.noarch       el6-8                        @/mysql57-community-release-el6-8.noarch
mysql-community-client.i686            5.7.13-1.el7                 mysql57-community
mysql-community-client.x86_64          5.7.13-1.el7                 mysql57-community
mysql-community-common.i686            5.7.13-1.el7                 mysql57-community
mysql-community-common.x86_64          5.7.13-1.el7                 mysql57-community
mysql-community-devel.i686             5.7.13-1.el7                 mysql57-community
mysql-community-devel.x86_64           5.7.13-1.el7                 mysql57-community
mysql-community-embedded.i686          5.7.13-1.el7                 mysql57-community
mysql-community-embedded.x86_64        5.7.13-1.el7                 mysql57-community
mysql-community-embedded-compat.i686   5.7.13-1.el7                 mysql57-community
mysql-community-embedded-compat.x86_64 5.7.13-1.el7                 mysql57-community
mysql-community-embedded-devel.i686    5.7.13-1.el7                 mysql57-community
mysql-community-embedded-devel.x86_64  5.7.13-1.el7                 mysql57-community
mysql-community-libs.i686              5.7.13-1.el7                 mysql57-community
mysql-community-libs.x86_64            5.7.13-1.el7                 mysql57-community
mysql-community-libs-compat.i686       5.7.13-1.el7                 mysql57-community
mysql-community-libs-compat.x86_64     5.7.13-1.el7                 mysql57-community
mysql-community-release.noarch         el7-7                        mysql57-community
mysql-community-server.x86_64          5.7.13-1.el7                 mysql57-community
mysql-community-test.x86_64            5.7.13-1.el7                 mysql57-community
mysql57-community-release.noarch       el7-7                        mysql57-community
```

so it appears that the el6-8 link is installing references to el7 ???

when I try to install mysql with `sudo yum install mysql` i get the following errors

```
Downloading packages:
http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.7-community/el/6/x86_64/mysql-community-client-5.7.13-1.el7.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.7-community/el/6/x86_64/mysql-community-common-5.7.13-1.el7.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.7-community/el/6/x86_64/mysql-community-libs-5.7.13-1.el7.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
```

when I try `sudo yum install mysql-community-server` i get error:

```
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.13-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: systemd
```

...which is a common error when trying to install el7 on el6 linux (which doesn't use systemd)

In both cases yum is trying to download the el7 package from the el6-8 repo...

how do I correct this ?

PS I've tried editing the `/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo` file but there's nothing that specifies the linux version
PPS I've also completely uninstalled the yum repo and tried `yum clean all` - then check  `yum list all |grep mysql57` which gives no results - followed by a fresh install = same result

**UPDATE**
the contents of my `/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo` file confirms that the repo is set up to load el6 mysql:

```
[mysql-connectors-community]
name=MySQL Connectors Community
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/el/6/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql

[mysql-tools-community]
name=MySQL Tools Community
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-community/el/6/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql

# Enable to use MySQL 5.5
[mysql55-community]
name=MySQL 5.5 Community Server
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.5-community/el/6/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql

# Enable to use MySQL 5.6
[mysql56-community]
name=MySQL 5.6 Community Server
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.6-community/el/6/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql

[mysql57-community]
name=MySQL 5.7 Community Server
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.7-community/el/6/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql

[mysql-tools-preview]
name=MySQL Tools Preview
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-preview/el/6/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
```

Comment: what does your `/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo` contain? can you paste it here?

Comment: additionally can you try to `yum clean all` first and then `yum update`, lastly make sure you're not on el7?

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too and it took me days to figure out. I, too, thought I was on an EL 7 OS, but I was on 6. I tried to install MySQL EL7 package and received the errors about needing systemd. This was the first clue that the package was incorrect.

I removed the EL7 packages with

```
sudo yum remove mysql57-community-release-el7-9.noarch
```

and installed EL6, but when running

```
sudo yum install mysql-community-server
```

it defaulted back to installing EL7 packages. I checked my /etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo, but all of that pointed to 6, not 7.

After days of fighting with this,

```
sudo yum clean all
```

and

```
sudo yum update
```

fixed the problem. After that, sudo yum install mysql-community-server worked perfectly.

Comment: thanks for the response - however I knew my server was el6 the whole time and was trying to install el6 packages - but the el6 yum links (listed in the question UPDATE section) consistently downloaded el7 packages. I had also tried the `sudo yum clean all` followed by fresh install & `sudo yum update` as noted in the question.  from memory (it's a a couple of months ago now) the repos were updated and the links corrected within a few days of posting the question.

Comment: +1, because I am blind as a bat, and didn't notice that you (@goredwards) had both the mysql release packages for el7 and el6 installed. Removing the el7 release package should indeed solve the problem.